# Trying to save a raster with only field information

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, attribute-table, fields-attributes

I'm fairly new to all GIS.

I am using the Wise30secfin.ovr file which has prepopulated fields in an attribute table. I want to make a raster with the values from only one field, but every time I try to save the new layer, the values become simple numbers instead of the specific AC/AL/AN ...(etc) data that I need from the dominant soil types.

In essence I need a raster that shows the global dominant soil type in that area (only).
Using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.2

Comment: Can you find a lookup table in your files or documentation that associates the numbers to the descriptive text? That is likely what you are seeing.

Comment: There's an enormous .mdb file with it, but nothing that seems to specifically code for these, only this line as instructions;  Using ArcMap users may join the raster data to the derived soil properties files, as managed in the MSAccess database (Wise30sec.mdb). Linkage is through the map unit code or grid cell identifier (NEWSUID) of the raster set and the NEWSUID of the various soil attribute data files. The above files are also provided in TIFF and TXT format (see folder "...\Interchangeable_format") so that they may be easily accessed using other systems.